# What is the name of the figure using flags performed by Adam in Mythbusters episode 209?

Tags: short-stick

Early on in the Mythbusters episode 209 (Car Chase Chaos/Animal Antics) Adam uses both arms to spin two flags in a nice figure. I'd like to know if that figure has a name, and if so, to learn more about it; e.g., does it come from a particular discipline?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it has nothing to do with martial arts.

Comment: Second. If it's your assertion this is martial arts related, please post a video, and why you feel this is on topic (how it relates to martial arts).

Comment: As I said below, he is referring to an Escrima/Kali drill, which should qualify it as martial arts related.

Comment: @JuannStrauss there is no evidence of that. Barring an example, are we to simply take your word on it?

Comment: 1. Watch the Youtube videos I linked. 2. Watch the relevant MythBusters episode.

Answer (score 3):

What you are referring to is probably a Kali/Escrima sinawali drill.

E.g. http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rum-D53fRiM

The guy in the below video is full of it, but it does demonstrate what you're talking about.

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rk3pmvNe-eY

Comment: It's painful how inappropriate it would be to -1 this for using Rick Tew as a paragon for any answer. Anybody else remember Tew-ryu?

Comment: Which is why I said "The guy in the below video is full of it" and added an actual Escrima video too ;)